# BigQuery Partition table

Tags: google-bigquery

How to create BigQuery Partition table in Bigquery WebUI. I know we can create from gcloud and api. 
I searched webUI but couldn't find any option for creating partition table from WebUI.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

We added support for this recently and expect the UI to show it once the changes are deployed. I will provide an update once that is done. Thanks!

Comment: is there any ETA on this?

Comment: Tentatively within a week. I will provide an update when it is available. Thanks!

Comment: any update on this? and also on this issue as well?  https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=611